# Window.popup Does not keep Session values

Tags: jquery, ajax, session, popupwindow

When system is in main window it acts well , but sometimes when i generate bill through ajax and after generate bill window.popup open automatically for show details in bill format.
on that time log in session is not stored,
in short when window.popup open session value is blank and after refresh main screen system will be log-out.
**possibilities :**
**Ajax is creating issue for session 

Window.popup does not support session .**

Please help Give me suggestion .....

Answer (score 0):

*Ajax is creating issue for session* i really dont think so

*Window.popup does not support session*  nope, it does support session
your issue is you are starting new session with another id. include the following on top every page
if you are on php for starting the session

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
```

including the page that opens up on popup